# etc/bash.bashrc: line 2: GREP_OPTIONS: command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

When I run a command on my Ubuntu 12 server I get the following warning...

```
etc/bash.bashrc: line 2: GREP_OPTIONS: command not found
```

I've probably messed something up by uninstalling various Rails pieces.  How can I fix this?  This is for the root user.  Thanks.

The beginning of my bashrc file has the following...

> type rvm >/dev/null 2>/dev/null || echo ${PATH} | GREP_OPTIONS \grep
>   "" > /dev/null || export PATH="${PATH}:"

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the full bash.bashrc file. The 2nd line of the script is trying to run `GREP_OPTIONS` as a command, so there's probably a spacing issue around the `=`.

Comment: Added the first lines of the bashrc file to question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you have uninstalled `rvm` from your system, as it cannot find `$rvm_path_bin`. I would recommend commenting out the line from `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

Comment: I commented out type rvm >/dev/null 2>/dev/null || echo ${PATH} | GREP_OPTIONS \grep "" > /dev/null || export PATH="${PATH}:" and it is no longer giving me a warning, thanks.

Comment: Is commenting out really correct solution if I actually have rvm installed on my system?